# Prove that $PA$, $PB$ and $PC$ are the lengths of the sides of a triangle.

Tags: geometry

> Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle and let $P$ be a point that does not belong to the circumcircle of $\triangle{ABC}$. Prove that $PA$, $PB$ and $PC$ are the lengths of the sides of a triangle.

I got $$\begin{array} \\s+PA > z \\ s+PB > PC \\ PB+PA > s \end{array}$$ where $s$ is the side length of the equilateral triangle if we assume $P$ to be opposite side $AB$. Provign that $PA,PB,PC$ form the sides of a triangle in this case is enough to prove the claim. I am unsure how to proceed though.

Comment: Hint: Ptolemy's inequality.

Comment: @Wojowu I used that and got $PA+PB \geq PC$. How do I show equality doesn't hold and also the other inequalities for the triangle inequality?

Comment: turn $\triangle PAB$ ,let $AB$ to $CB$, now $P$ to $P'$, what is relation of $PP'$ and $PC$?

Comment: Equality would hold only when PABC is cyclic quadrilateral, but since there is condition that P is not on circumcircle of ABC, the equality never holds.